# Rails webscraper works in console, but not server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I've been hammering out some methods and testing them in the console. The problem is that an error occurs when running on the server. Specifically, the first method below triggers this `NoMethod` error:

```
undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's the code. It's from the webpage.rb file, which has a uri column.

```
def download_page_title
  page_as_xml.at_css('title').text
end

def page_as_xml
  page_as_xml ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(page_uri))
end

def page_uri
  base_uri = Site.find_by_id(self.site_id).homepage #always has "/" at end
  if self.url == base_uri
    page_uri = base_uri
  else
    page_uri = "#{base_uri}#{self.url}"
  end
end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Also, any idea why things go smoothly in console but derail on the server?

EDIT: Here's an example of what I'm doing in console.

```
1.9.3p194 :262 > a = Webpage.new( url: "http://www.cnn.com/", site_id:165)
 => #<Webpage id: nil, url: "http://www.cnn.com/", site_id: 165, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, title: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :263 > a.download_page_title
  Site Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "sites".* FROM "sites" WHERE "sites"."id" = 165 LIMIT 1
 => "CNN.com - Breaking News, U.S., World, Weather, Entertainment & Video News"
```

Comment: What exactly are you running in the console that is working?

Comment: If I create a new website, give it an url of something like `"http://www.cnn.com"`, and save it, then I can call the download_page_title method successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `page_as_xml.at_css` is returning `nil`, and you're then trying to call `.text` on that `nil` object.

So, figure out why that's returning `nil`. For example, does the page you're downloading not specify a `title` tag that is accessible via CSS selectors? Is the page blank or return no result? Does it return an error status (something not in the 2xx HTTP status range)?

To say it another way, there's probably an upstream difference between the pages you're using for testing versus what the server is actually getting.

You might need to handle (or throw an exception, or log/report) pages that return `nil` from a call to `page_as_xml.at_css` - that really depends on what your software needs to do.

Comment: I'm using the same page in console as I am when I run the app locally.  But yes, I agree that I'll need some exception handling eventually.  I just want to get it to work right first.

Comment: If you're using the same page in testing and production, then you need to post some details about how the page is being set/retrieved, and prove that it's not `nil` before the first method is called in production. If you can't prove that the page isn't already `nil` before the call to the first method, then the problem may be happening before that method call is placed.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  There's a nil value way before I even get to the webscraping code.  Good insight.  Thank you.